# NodeJS MongoDB: Type Number can't save as array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a more than one inputs with numbers so I need a output that look like this:
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1] but instead of that it output this in console log: ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1"] and in mongodb like this: ["1,1,1,1,1"].

In models if I set to be like this:

```
numbers: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
}
```

This is code that I use for mongodb with mongoose:

```
router.post('/', (req, res)=>{
    const newResult = Result({
      numbers: req.body.numbers
    });

    newResult.save()
        .then(savedResult=>{
            ElectoralUnit.find({})
                .then(electoralUnits=>{
                    res.redirect('/results');
                });
         });
});
```

I get the following Error:

```
error: (node:5696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: StateResult 
validation failed: numbers: Cast to Number failed for value "[ '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' ]" 
at path "numbers"
```

I tried to put `type: [Number]` but no luck.

but if I set to String instead of number then is without error but string instead of integer in mongodb. How to set array to integer?

Comment: Are you using Mongoose? Where is the code you are using to update and or save documents? If you want to save an Array of numbers, you have to set up your model differently: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: `type: [Number]`

Comment: I update the question. Yes I use mongoose and yes I tried type: [Number]

Comment: You should definitely use `type: [Number]` since you are storing an array of numbers. The question is whether or not `req.body.numbers` is an array of Numbers or an array of Strings. It seems you are getting Strings. Check how the array is being inputted. Then, consider doing some data validation before creating a new document. `const validated = req.body.numbers.map(num=> Number(num))`

Comment: It seems that [Number] work, it shows: numbers: Array 0: 1 1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1. I don't know why it wasn't work first time that I tried, maybe I was change something else in that point... But again if I console.log it shows: [ '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' ] Why is that?

Comment: Where you are calling `console.log()`?

Comment: Before insertiong into mongodb. let numbers = req.body.numbers; console.log(numbers);

Comment: According to the documentation, it seems that when you set a datatype of "Number" Mongoose will convert the value it receives into a Number if it can. https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/4.13.12/lib/schema/number.js

So the second step I mentioned in my comment above about mapping your data before saving is not necessary since Mongoose will do that for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will read docs but for now is working ;)

Comment: I'll put the answer below and you can accept it.

Comment: Sure, thanks once again ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are attempting to store an array of Numbers, and since Mongoose will convert number-like strings into [JavaScript Numbers](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/4.13.12/lib/schema/number.js), you need to make sure you are in fact storing an Array of Numeric Digits and define your Scheme-type as

```
numbers: {
    type: [Number],
    required: true
}
```

Be sure to validate inputs on both the front-end and back-end. To avoid the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`, be sure to add a `.catch()` to your `.save()` function and send the appropriate response to your front end.